# what is regular expression required to validate images

Tags: .net, regex

i trying to upload images  to folder. here  i need  to  upload  only images like
  .JPEG|.jpeg|GIF|.gif|.PNG|.png|bmp|.BMP

what is expression that we should  write here  so that when  ever user  tryis   to upload thier files  rather  than this

any solution  would   be great
 thank you

Answer (score 4):

Generally that's a bad idea, but...

```
/(jpg|gif|bmp|png)$/
```

Run the expression with whatever language you're using and make sure you make it case insensitive.

I say it's a bad idea, because you're better off checking the actual data in the file after the upload occurs.  I can rename a file to anything I want and upload it to your site.

ETA: the forward slashes may be optional in your language.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the hole big enough to drive a truck through :-) And I've seen .jpeg files as well, whether you want to cover those is a matter of taste - I'd rather ditch the file name checking altogether as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work with:

\w*.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ 
Using this, you need to use IgnoreCase in asp.net.

\w are all alphanumeric characters followed by a dot (escaped because it is a special character). Then one of your extensions.

But remember: Files are not identified by their extension, but by their content. You might be able to use something alike to linux "file" utility for identifying the type of file. I don't know if something similar exists for asp.net